# Windows 10 New Install Error 0xc0000221 Missing Kernel

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

I am trying to install windows 10 onto a computer.  This should be a new/fresh install but I had motherboard issues and have since replaced the motherboard.  When attempting to load the installation media windows is trying to recover my computer, which is not what I am trying to do.

Screen Messages:

- Recovery
- Your PC/Device needs to be repaired
- The operating system
  couldn't load because the kernel is missing or contains errors.
- File\windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
- Error code: 0xc0000221

Then I get a bunch of recover tool options if I press F8 or Enter same message pops up.  I am just trying to do a fresh operating system install, format disk, select disk for OS install.  I am not sure if the disk contains a windows 10 install or not but regardless I get the same error message even when I disconnect the disk before booting, with installation media connected.

I have used both an OEM Windows 10 disk and USB installation media.  I am using a Gigabyte motherboard B150M-D3H-GSM and am less familiar with the BIOS as I have always previously used ASUS but have been sent 2 bad motherboards that wouldn't post so I decided to make a switch.  I checked and current motherboard is listed as windows 10 ready.

In the past Windows 7 new OS installs has been a breeze but this is only my second Windows 10 install that wasn't using a VM.

Any searches seem to be around either errors with windows already installed or errors after installation has started, to a disk...which is connected.  Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit**
Just confirmed the disk I was using is brand new, no OS previously installed.

Comment: Any chance of the DVD is corrupted?

Comment: I have tried both an OEM win 10 DVD and usb installation media that I created from an ISO file, that I have used to created Win 10 VM's with.

Comment: [I should be getting to a screen like this one but am not](http://www.windows10.windowsreinstall.com/images/install_images/imgF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like bad stick of RAM causing strange error messages in Windows during attempted OS install.  Replaced with new RAM and was able to install OS properly.